# Avoid close command line window at end

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, c++-cli

on Visual C++ 2010 cli, I can execute without problems as follow:

```
comando = "-F -v -pm328p -cstk500v1 -P " + comboBox1->SelectedItem->ToString() +" -D -Uflash:w:C:\\ll.hex:i";
Process::Start( "avrdude.exe", comando );
```

but at the end of executing, the window closes automaticaly.

How can I avoid the automatic closing? I wish not to use batch file...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved creating a batch file as follow:

```
avrdude %*
pause
```

and changing

and changing my code in this way:

```
Process::Start( "avrdude.bat", comando );
```

Comment: You can avoid the need for a batch file by calling "cmd.exe" with the "/k" argument. See "cmd /?".

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a getchar() or cin in the last line of your program before return
So the program waits for an input and won't close automatically

Comment: avrdude.exe it a third part program, I can't modify it